# Get array objects with specific ObjectId in nested array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, go, aggregate, mgo

I'm trying to get a specific array of objects depending on ObjectId they have.

Here is my MongoDB database:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59edb571593904117884b721"),
    "userids" : [
            ObjectId("59edb459593904117884b71f")
    ],
    "macaddress" : "MACADDRESS",
    "devices" : [ ],
    "projectorbrand" : "",
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59edb584593904117884b722"),
    "userids" : [
            ObjectId("59edb459593904117884b71f"),
            ObjectId("59e4809159390431d44a9438")
    ],
    "macaddress" : "MACADDRESS2",
    "devices" : [ ],
    "projectorbrand" : "",
}
```

The command in MongoDB is:

```
db.getCollection('co4b').find( {
    userids: { $all: [ ObjectId("59edb459593904117884b71f") ] }
} )
```

This will work and will return an array filtered correctly.
I would like to translate this query in Golang.

Here is my code:

```
pipe := bson.M{"userids": bson.M{"$all": objectId}}
var objects[]models.Objects
if err := uc.session.DB("API").C("objects").Pipe(pipe).All(&objects); err != nil {
    SendError(w, "error", 500, err.Error())
} else {
    for i := 0; i < len(objects); i++ {
        objects[i].Actions = nil
    }
    uj, _ := json.MarshalIndent(objects, "", " ")
    SendSuccessJson(w, uj)
}
```

I'm getting error like `wrong type for field (pipeline) 3 != 4`. I saw that `$all` needs string array but how to filter by ObjectId instead of string?

Thanks for help

Comment: When are you getting the error? While running go code or while compiling it?

Comment: while running go code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to use the aggregation framework in your `mgo` solution, yet the query you try to implement does not use one (and does not need one).

The query:

```
db.getCollection('co4b').find({
    userids: {$all: [ObjectId("59edb459593904117884b71f")] }
})
```

Can simply be transformed to `mgo` like this:

```
c := uc.session.DB("API").C("objects")

var objects []models.Objects
err := c.Find(bson.M{"userids": bson.M{
    "$all": []interface{}{bson.ObjectIdHex("59edb459593904117884b71f")},
}}).All(&objects)
```

Also note that if you're using `$all` with a single element, you can also implement that query using `$elemMatch`, which in MongoDB console would like this:

```
db.getCollection('co4b').find({
    userids: {$elemMatch: {$eq: ObjectId("59edb459593904117884b71f")}}
})
```

Which looks like this in `mgo`:

```
err := c.Find(bson.M{"userids": bson.M{
    "$elemMatch": bson.M{"$eq": bson.ObjectIdHex("59edb459593904117884b71f")},
}}).All(&objects)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer ! It's perfect with $elemMatch !